# Flutter creating custom user model with querying firestore gives " type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' " error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I keep username at firestore like Users > username > username:username, mail:mail
I am using email, pass auth.

I want to create a custom user model to keep current user's username and mail. I can successfully reach username in findCurrentUser() function with using currentUser.email but when I tried to create a model with what findCurrentUser function returns, I got error.

Here is full error:

> ════════ Exception caught by provider
> ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following assertion was thrown: An exception was throw by
> _MapStream<User, CustomUser> listened by
>
> StreamProvider, but no `catchError` was provided.
>
> Exception: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Here is my functions and model:

```
  class CustomUser {
  final String email;
  final String username;

  CustomUser({this.email, this.username,});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'email': email,
        'username': username
      };
  }


  dynamic findCurrentUser() async {
    var email = _firebaseAuth.currentUser.email;
    var user =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .where('email', isEqualTo: email).get().then((value) => value.docs.first.data()['username']);
    print('user); 
    return user; 
  }

  CustomUser customUser(User user) {
    return user != null
        ? CustomUser(email: user.email, username:  findCurrentUser())
        : null;
  }

  Stream<CustomUser> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(customUser);
  }
```

And my provider :

```
 StreamProvider(
        create: (context) =>
        context.read<AuthenticationService>().user,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You always need to resolve a future before using it, even if you called await on a future and resolved it in a method, an async method returns a future again.

In this particular case, you're calling  `findCurrentUser` which returns a `Future` for a string field, hence the error.

- here are some fixes,

since you only have user and email in your model, I'd suggest using the `User` that `onAuthStateChange` returns.

if you still want to continue with the model, you don't really need to make that extra query, if all you need is email and username, you can directly get it from firebase auth.

The easiest way now is to map the user within one function and then cal to fix your error.

```dart
Future<CustomUser> findCurrentUser(User user) async {
    var email = _firebaseAuth.currentUser.email;

    var user =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
        .get().then((value) => value.docs.first.data()['username']);
    
    return CustomUser(email: user.email, username: user); 
  }


Stream<CustomUser> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(findCurrentUser);
  }
```